# Startup script from Bitbucket (https) fail to download, but works if instance is reset

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am programatically launching a new instance using the Compute Engine API for Go [1], and a tool I made called vmproxy [2].

The problem I have is that if I launch a preemptible VM using a startup-script-url pointing to https://bitbucket.org/ronoaldo/debian-custom/raw/tip/tools/autobuild, the build script fails to download. I can see in the serial console output that the the startup script metadata is there, and that it attempts to be downloaded with curl, but that part fails.

However, if I reset the instance via the developers console, the script is properly downloaded and runs nicelly.

The code I am using to setup the instance is:

```
// Ronolinux is a VM Proxy that runs an live systems build on Compute Engine
var (
    Ronolinux = &vmproxy.VM{
        Path: "/",
        Instance: vmproxy.Instance{
            Name:        "ronolinux-buildd",
            Zone:        "us-central1-f",
            Image:       vmproxy.ResourcePrefix + "/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-8-jessie-v20150915",
            MachineType: "n1-standard-1",
            Metadata: map[string]string{
                "startup-script-url": "https://bitbucket.org/ronoaldo/debian-custom/raw/tip/tools/autobuild",
                "shutdown-script": `!#/bin/bash
gsutil cp /var/log/startupscript.log gs://ronoaldo/ronolinux/build-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).log
`,
            },  
            Scopes: []string{ storageReadWrite },
        },  
    }   
)
```

[1] https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1

[2] https://godoc.org/ronoaldo.gopkg.net/aetools/vmproxy

Answer (score 0):

If your startup script is not hosted on Cloud Storage, there is a random chance the download will fail. If you look at the serial console output, make sure to scroll horizontally, as it will not wrap long lines. In my case, the error line was very long, and this hidded the real end of the message:

```
(... long curl on-line progress output )
curl: (7) Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Connection timed out
(...)
```

Your host must respond within a 10s timeout. In my case, the first boot usually failed to contact Bitbucket, hence failing to download the script; a VM reset also made things work, as the network latency outside Google Cloud were probably better.

I ended up moving to host the script on cloud storage to avoid these issues.